# How can I sum on this query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using Postgres. This returns all payments grouped by user which works fine.

```
@users_with_payments = Payment.all(select: 'distinct(users.*)', joins: :user)
```

I need to sum the total payments amounts for each user to order by that amount. When trying this I get this error

```
@users_with_payments = Payment.all(select: 'distinct(users.*), SUM(payments.amount_cents)', joins: :user)
```

`PG::Error: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT distinct(users.*), SUM(payments.amount_cents) FROM "p...`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and what would be the right way to construct this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using **postgres** as reported by the error `column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause`.  You should simply add `Group by users.id` at the end of your request.